# ng-show and localStorage behaving odd

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, local-storage

I am just trying to hide something when a localStorage key is set to null, and show it when the key is not null. The key is called `articles`and the way I am trying to check is:

```
$scope.isEmpty = function isEmpty() {
  return localStorage.getItem('articles') !== null;
};
```

then in my html:

```
<li ng-show="isEmpty()"> There is actually something to see here </li>
```

the local storage key (from chrome dev tools) looks like this:

```
**key**         **Value**
articles          null
```

is there any particular reason why this isnt working? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage` can only store string values.

`localStorage` stores `null` as string. When you use strict comparison operator it'll not work. You can use string `'null'` with strict comparison.

```
return localStorage.getItem('articles') !== 'null';
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! I was completely unaware of that. even checked the structure in dev tools compared to other keys that are storing strings which do have the ' ' wrapping them. oh well. Thanx again

Comment: will mark as the correct answer in 10 minutes when it lets me

Comment: You can't use `!= null`. `'null' == null` is `false`.